# NullReferenceException working with a webcam

Tags: c#, webcam, nullreferenceexception

I'm making a software in C# for College School and I need a help with this:

[image]

Youtube tutorial used: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaYQLq72ZN4

> an error occurred while capturing the video image. the video capture
>   will now be terminated. Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

The first time executed the software, it worked perfectly, now when I closed and opened again gave this error (it seems that a process is running).
I followed a tutorial from youtube, I noticed that there were many complaints because of a similar error.
It works yes, but only if you press 3 times the button "start", I have no idea of the error.

CODES:

FRM:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WinApp_FingerControl
{
    public partial class Frm_CadastroCliente : Form
    {

        public Frm_CadastroCliente()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        WebCam webcam;
        private void Frm_CadastroCliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam = new WebCam();
            webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref imgVideo);
        }

        private void btn_IniciarCamera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam.Start();
        }

        private void btn_Salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Helper.SaveImageCapture(imgCapture.Image);
        }

        private void btn_FormatoVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam.ResolutionSetting();
        }

        private void btnCapturar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webcam.AdvanceSetting();
        }


    }
}
```

Webcam.cs:

```
{

    class WebCam
    {
        private WebCamCapture webcam;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox _FrameImage;
        private int FrameNumber = 30;
        public void InitializeWebCam(ref System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ImageControl)
        {
            webcam = new WebCamCapture();
            webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
            webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
            webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
            _FrameImage = ImageControl;
        }

        void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
        {
            _FrameImage.Image = e.WebCamImage;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
                webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
                webcam.Start(0);
        }

        public void ResolutionSetting()
        {
            webcam.Config();
        }

        public void AdvanceSetting()
        {
            webcam.Config2();
        }

    }
}
```

Helper.cs

```
class Helper
{

    public static void SaveImageCapture(System.Drawing.Image image)
    {

        SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
        s.FileName = "Image";// Default file name
        s.DefaultExt = ".Jpg";// Default file extension
        s.Filter = "Image (.jpg)|*.jpg"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (s.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Save Image
            string filename = s.FileName;
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            image.Save(fstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            fstream.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: Is there any other stack trace information associated with this error? A line number or a method name? Those would be good clues to help focus on where the error is coming from.

Comment: Now I have the same issue. Is there anyone out there who can help ??

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Is any solution regarding this exception, I'm facing same issue with webcame_capture.dll lib.

Answer (score -6):

Kill the processes of other applications like Skype that use the webcam and your code will run. :)